# Flex: Access member variable by using a variable in the name

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can I access the member variable of an object by using a variable in the name.

Example:

Entries Object has properties 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Normally I would access them by

```
var i : int = Entries.1;
var i : int = Entries.2;
```

However, if I have a loop

```
for (var j : int = 1; j < 6; j++){
  trace(Entries[j]);
}
```

does not work.

```
 Entries.(j)
 Entries.j
```

neither.

What's the way to go?

```
Entries.hasOwnProperty("j")
```

also does not work to check if the member exists.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the Entries object? In my testing, I can access numerically named properties just fine using Entries[j].

Comment: without converting them to a string?
The Entries object comes from the backend via ZendAMF. It gets mapped to a Standard Object in Flex with a couple of members. In debug mode I can see them with [1], [2], [3] as members of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Entries.hasOwnProperty("j")
```

does not work because you're sending it "j" as a string, you need to convert the integer variable j to a string, therefore representing the number you are looking for. Eg:

```
Entries.hasOwnProperty(j.toString());
```

So to extract the property from your object, you can do:

```
for(var j:int = 1; j < 6; j++)
{
    trace(Entries[j.toString()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not that I needed to convert it to a String. Works perfectly now.